# how to allocate file in disk to write data c++

Tags: c#, c++, download

I'm trying to use curl to download data from internet with multi-part simultaneous using multiple thread. However, I have problems when the download is done, I must merge all the parts together, and this wastes memory and take too long.

I see [Torrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/features.html) and Flashget using this technique whose name I don't know. Before the download, Torrent gets the content length of a file and auto allocates an empty file in disk. After that, the downloaded data will fill this allocated file, if the download is resumed. Torrent or Flashget will check this allocate file to get the bytes it has already downloaded and they resume the download.

Anyone can help me with this technique, or give me some link to documents about this? It would be great if you can suggest me example using c# or c++. Thanks for help

Comment: Well you could [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541(v=vs.85).aspx) to whatever length you want and then [SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531(v=vs.85).aspx) to extend it, however I'm not sure that will help with _"Torrent or Flash get will check this allocate file to get byte has download and resume download"_.  You will need to keep track of what was downloaded still.   _[This might be useful too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434306/in-general-how-does-resuming-a-download-work)_

Comment: Do you mean sparse files? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pre-allocate file on disk, you can do as following:

**1.** Open file for writing.

```
HANDLE file = CreateFile("some_file.bin", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

**2.** Move file pointer to desired location.

```
LONG download_size = /* check, how much data is going to be downloaded */;
SetFilePointer(file, download_size, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
```

**3.** Physically extend file.

```
SetEndOfFile(file);
```

More information:

- [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

As for this part:

> check this allocate file to get byte has download and resume download.

You can achieve this, by storing partial download in a custom format with header. For example, define a struct:

```
struct TmpDownloadInfo
{
    uint32_t header_size;
    size_t downloaded_bytes;
    //other fields?
};
```

Then, store temporary data in file, that begins with this header and update it on each modification (of course, remember, that in this case, you will need to preallocate `download_size + sizeof(TmpDownloadInfo)`). When download is completed, you can either remove this header and update file size or copy whole data to a new, result file (perhaps "merging" on-the-fly?).

Comment: thanks @Mateusz Grzejek. im using your suggest and pre-allocate file succesful. but im using WriteFile to write data into pre-allocate file but not success. here my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188022/libcurl-write-data-with-writefile-winapi)