# libCurl write data with WriteFile WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, curl

i using libcurl to download data form internet. if using FILE to write data downloaded is ok. but i want pre-allocate data and write it. im using

[CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[SetEndOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

to pre-allocate file with prefix size data. After that im using [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx) to write data downloaded but not successful. File is corrupt or fail, cannot open or using it. This is my simple code, anyone have idea to fix writeData method. Thanks all

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

#include <curl\curl.h>

using namespace std;
size_t writeData(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, HANDLE *userdata){    
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;
    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        userdata,           // open file handle
        buffer,      // start of data to write
        (size*nmemb),  // number of bytes to write
        0, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);  
    return nmemb;   
}
int progressData(void *ptr, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow){    
    cout << "DOWNLOADED: " << dlnow / 1024 << "KB  TOTAL SIZE: " << dltotal / 1024 << "KB" << endl;
    return 0;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl; 
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    string url = "http://myserver.allmedia.com/games/NgaoKiem300115/sampleFile.zip";
    string save = "E:\\Downloads\\sampleFile.zip";          

    HANDLE file = CreateFile("E:\\Downloads\\sampleFile.zip", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        cout << "ALLOCATE FILE FAIL" << endl;       
    }

    SetFilePointer(file, 486702722, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetEndOfFile(file);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){

        fp = fopen(save.c_str(), "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &file);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progressData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);      

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    }       
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't perform very much error checking so who knows what could be going wrong? This is the single most common mistake that beginners make with Win32e. Always check for errors, as described by the documentation.

Looking at your code, you don't move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file before starting to write to the file. That alone means you code cannot work. Perhaps there are more errors, but I've not dug any deeper.

You would do well to perform some debugging. Trying to solve problems by staring at code doesn't always succeed. Inspect the program whilst it executes. Learn how to debug.

Comment: thanks @David Heffernan. i have move the file pointer back to begin `SetFilePointer(file, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);`  and wirte data success. but i wonder. if i have file 40MB. i write from 0 to 20MB im stop download end exit program. After load program again, how to read file in Disk to know position pointer has written data.

Answer (score 0):

You are making quite a few mistakes:

1. you are not seeking the file pointer back to 0 after pre-sizing the file, so your writes will start at the end of the file.
2. you are passing your file `HANDLE` to your `writeData()` function via a pointer, which is fine, but you are not dereferencing that pointer when calling `WriteFile()`, so it will always fail.
3. you are not reporting an error to libCurl if `WriteFile()` fails.
4. you are opening multiple handles, of different type, to the same file, and you are not closing any of them when you are done downloading.
5. you are passing a `string` instead of a `char*` to `CURLOPT_URL`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

#include <curl\curl.h>

using namespace std;

size_t writeData(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, HANDLE *userdata)
{    
    DWORD dwWritten;
    BOOL bResult = WriteFile(
        *userdata,          // open file handle
        buffer,      // start of data to write
        (size*nmemb),  // number of bytes to write
        &dwWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL));
    if (!bResult) {
        return 0;  
    }
    return dwWritten;   
}

int progressData(void *ptr, double dltotal, double dlnow, double ultotal, double ulnow)
{    
    cout << "DOWNLOADED: " << dlnow / 1024 << "KB  TOTAL SIZE: " << dltotal / 1024 << "KB" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CURL *curl; 
    CURLcode res;
    string url = "http://myserver.allmedia.com/games/NgaoKiem300115/NgaoKiem.zip";
    string save = "E:\\Downloads\\NgaoKiem.zip";            

    HANDLE file = CreateFileA(save.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << "CREATE FILE FAIL, ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;       
        goto done;
    }

    if (SetFilePointer(file, 486702722, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
        cout << "ALLOCATE FILE FAIL, ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (!SetEndOfFile(file)) {
        cout << "ALLOCATE FILE FAIL, ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (SetFilePointer(file, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {
        cout << "PREPARE FILE FAIL, ERROR " << GetLastError() << endl;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        cout << "CURL INIT FAIL" << endl;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &file);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progressData);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, FALSE);      

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);    
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        cout << "CURL DOWNLOAD FAIL, ERROR " << res << endl;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

cleanup:
    CloseHandle(file);

done:
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```